# Running git from python - inconsistent output compared to runing in shell

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to extract some info from git via python script. I have a script like this:

```
import os
import subprocess


result = None
command = [ "git", "log", "--since=\"2022-10-13T17:40:05.232777\"", "--name-only", "--pretty=format:'%f'" ]
print("RUN: "+" ".join(command))
try:
    result = subprocess.run(command, check=True, capture_output=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    result = e
print("Stdout:")
print(result.stdout.decode("utf8"))
print("Stderr:")
print(result.stderr.decode("utf8"))
```

And this is the output:

```
RUN: git log --since="2022-10-13T17:40:05.232777" --name-only --pretty=format:'%f'
Stdout:
'Even-more-test-files'
python/tests_index/secondtestfile.txt
python/tests_index/teeeeeeeeeest.txt

'More-test-files-for-git-log'
python/findtest.py

'Add-some-test-file'
python/tests_index/testfile.txt

Stderr:
```

But if I run it in bash, this is what I get:

```
Even-more-test-files
python/tests_index/secondtestfile.txt
python/tests_index/teeeeeeeeeest.txt

More-test-files-for-git-log
python/findtest.py

Add-some-test-file
python/tests_index/testfile.txt
```

Take note of the missing quotes. This is not the only inconsistency I've seen, but it is one that I was able to reproduce in a standalone file.

Why am I getting different output and how to ensure I see exactly what I'd see in console? The **why** question here is really important for me.

Comment: There is a GitPython package that may help you (https://pypi.org/project/GitPython/).

Answer (score 0):

When using `subprocess`, you have your choice of whether to invoke a shell:

```
subprocess.run(..., shell=True)
```

or not:

```
subprocess.run(..., shell=False)
```

If you do run things through a shell, the *shell* will break things up at spaces, interpret metacharacters like `*` and `&` and `|`, and so on.  This is convenient, but generally inadvisable, as [the old xkcd comic warns](https://xkcd.com/327/).

If you *don't* run things through the shell, you *must not* add quotes where the shell would have stripped them:

```
"--pretty=format:'%f'"
```

passes the literal single quotes through to the called program, which sees them, though had this whole thing been handled by a shell, the shell would have taken away the single quotes while protecting the `%f` characters from shell interpretation.  (Since neither `%` nor `f` get interpreted anyway, this isn't actually required, but in more complex formats you'd have spaces, which would be shell-interpreted.)